# std::getline removes whitespaces?

Tags: c++, whitespace

So I am creating a command line application and I am trying to allow commands with parameters, or if the parameter is enclosed with quotations, it will be treated as 1 parameter.

Example: test "1 2"

"test" will be the command, "1 2" will be a single parameter passed.

Using the following code snippet:

```
while(getline(t, param, ' ')) {
    if (param.find("\"") != string::npos) {
        ss += param;
        if (glue) {
            glue = false;
            params.push_back(ss);
            ss = "";
        }
        else {
            glue = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        params.push_back(param);
    }
}
```

However std::getline seems to auto remove whitespace which is causing my parameters to change from "1 2" to "12"

I've looked around but results are flooded with "How to remove whitespace" answers rather than "How to not remove whitespace"

Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, use GNU [`gengetopt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gengetopt/gengetopt.html) to automate making a `getopt_long`-based command-line parser ruleset, which — among other options — handles textual elements that are enclosed in quotation marks.

Answer (score 8):

> However std::getline seems to auto remove whitespace

That's exactly what you are telling getline to do:

```
getline(t, param, ' ');
```

The third argument in getline is the delimiter. If you want to parse the input line, you should read it until `'\n'` is found and then process it:

```
while(getline(t, param)) {
    /* .. */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my horrible logic T_T It looks like I may need to take a break.

Answer (score 1):

Umm, you are telling it to use `' '` as a delimiter in `std::getline`. Of course it's going to strip the whitespace.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/